# Elasticsearch concatenate two words into one

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field `ManufacturerName`

```
"ManufacturerName": {
    "type": "keyword",
    "normalizer" : "keyword_lowercase"
},
```

And a normalizer

```
"normalizer": {
    "keyword_lowercase": {
       "type": "custom",
       "filter": ["lowercase"]
    }
}
```

When searching for 'ripcurl' it matches. However when searching for 'rip curl' it doesn't.

How/what would use to concatenate certain words. i.e. 'rip curl' -> 'ripcurl'

Apologies if this is a duplicate, I've spent some time seeking a solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to make use of [`text`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/text.html) field for what you are looking for and get this kind of requirement carried out via [Ngram Tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html)

Below is a sample mapping, query and response:

### Mapping:

```
PUT mysomeindex
{
  "mappings": {
    "mydocs":{
      "properties": { 
        "ManufacturerName":{
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer", 
          "fields":{
            "keyword":{
              "type": "keyword",
              "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }, 
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "my_normalizer":{
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter": [],
          "filter": ["lowercase", "asciifolding"]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer",
          "filter": [ "synonyms" ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 5,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "synonyms":{
          "type": "synonym",
          "synonyms" : ["henry loyd, henry loid, henry lloyd => henri lloyd"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that the field `ManufacturerName` is a [multi-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) which has both `text` type and its sibling `keyword` type. That way for exact matches & for aggregation queries you could make use of `keyword` field while for this requirement you can make use of `text` field.

### Sample Document:

```
POST mysomeindex/mydocs/1
{
  "ManufacturerName": "ripcurl"
}

POST mysomeindex/mydocs/2
{
  "ManufacturerName": "henri lloyd"
}
```

What elasticsearch does when you ingest the above document is, it creates tokens of size from `3` to `5` length and stored them in inverted index for e.g. `rip, ipc, pcu etc...

You can execute the below query to see what tokens gets created:

```
POST mysomeindex/_analyze
{
  "text": "ripcurl",
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
}
```

Also I'd suggest you to look into [Edge Ngram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) tokenizer and see if that fits better for your requirement.

### Query:

```
POST mysomeindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "ManufacturerName": "rip curl"
    }
  }
}
```

### Response:

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.25316024,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "mysomeindex",
        "_type": "mydocs",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.25316024,
        "_source": {
          "ManufacturerName": "ripcurl"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

### Query for Synonyms:

```
POST mysomeindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "ManufacturerName": "henri lloyd"
    }
  }
}
```

### Response:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 2.2784421,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "mysomeindex",
        "_type": "mydocs",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 2.2784421,
        "_source": {
          "ManufacturerName": "henry lloyd"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Note:** If you intend to make use of synonyms then the best way it to have them in the a text file and add that relative to the `config` folder location as mentioned [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html#analysis-synonym-tokenfilter)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Brilliant, many thanks for this! I was hoping to also correct miss spelt words such as `"henry loyd, henry loid, henry lloyd => henri lloyd"`. Have just seen the synonym filter, tried to apply it but stating `Custom normalizer [keyword_filter] may not use filter [synonym]". Do you know how if I could combine the ngram tokeniser to achieve such result?

Comment: @atoms, I've updated my answer and added `synonyms filter` to the `text` type, however it is **not possible** to add the synonyms filter to the `keyword` type. It just violates what keyword stands for i.e. exact string match. Hope it helps!

Comment: @atoms, do note the last point I've mentioned. Happy to help!

Comment: Just attempted to PUT the new mappings and am recieving:
`"type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "The difference between max_gram and min_gram in NGram Tokenizer must be less than or equal to: [1] but was [2]. This limit can be set by changing the [index.max_ngram_diff] index level setting."
  },`. Seems odd to specify 1 as default range? Have changed settings to allow for 2

Comment: You can simply add this option under your settings `"max_ngram_diff": 2` or change the value of `max_ngram` to `4` in your tokenizer. So it basically depends on your requirement. If you think tokens of length 5 would be useful in your application, have the max as `5`. Note that having it larger would mean more tokens gets created for every word in your document, which would mean larger inverted index.

Comment: "type" : "mapper_exception", "reason" : "analyzer [eds_synonyms_analyzer] contains filters [eds_synonym_filter] that are not allowed to run in index time mode." } 
 in elastic search v7.15 
@OpsterESNinja-Kamal